# Why is $\ 1*_{\mathbb Z}\mathbb Z =\mathbb Z/2\mathbb Z=\{±1\}$?

Tags: algebraic-topology, fundamental-groups

> Why is $\ 1*_{\mathbb Z}\mathbb Z =\mathbb Z/2\mathbb Z=\{±1\}$ ?
>
> Our Professor got this result as the Fundamental group of $\mathbb RP^2$ by using Van-Kampen Theorem
>
> $*_{\mathbb Z}$ is the amalgamation

$\textbf{My Question}:$ the proof is clear, but the amalgamation not.

I think you can give me a short explanation, otherwise i can also write the whole proof.

edit: $\textbf{THE PROOF}$:

we parametrized $S^2$

$S^1\times[-\pi/2,\pi/2]\rightarrow S^2$

$(x,t)\mapsto cost(x,0)+sint(0,0,1)$

Let $U_1=p(upper hemisphere)$$\quad$p:projection from $S^2$ to $\mathbb RP^2$

$U_2=p(S^1\times (-\pi/4,\pi/4))$ then,

$U_1\cap U_2\simeq$  Cylinder

Then we used Van-Kampen

$\underbrace{\pi_1(U_1\cap U_2)}_{\mathbb Z}\longrightarrow\underbrace{\pi_1(U_1)}_{=1}$

$\downarrow$$\qquad$$\qquad$$\qquad$$\qquad$$\downarrow$

$\underbrace{\pi_1(U_2)}_{=\mathbb Z}\longrightarrow\pi_1(\mathbb RP^2)$

That's all then he wrote the result.

$\textbf{Here is the necessary part which i only need}$

According to the definition

If you have two mappings, $\psi_1,\psi_2$ with

$\psi_1:\mathbb Z\rightarrow 1$

$\psi_2:\mathbb Z\rightarrow\mathbb Z$

then $1*_{\mathbb Z}\mathbb Z=(1*\mathbb Z)/N$ where N is the normal subgroup generated by the elements of the form $\psi_1(a)\psi_2(a)\in 1*\mathbb Z$

and this must be equal to $\mathbb Z/2\mathbb Z$, and i ask WHY

Comment: It depends on the maps from the fundamental group of the intersection to the fundamental groups of the two pieces.

Comment: $1 *_\mathbb{Z} \mathbb{Z}$ is not defined until you specify a group morphism $\mathbb{Z} \to \mathbb{Z}$.

Comment: Do you mean $(x, t) \mapsto \cos t(x, 0, 0) + \sin t(0, 0, 1)$?. Also, what do you mean by '$U_1\cap U_2 \cong$ Möbius band, Cylinder'? It can't be both.

Comment: Sorry he wrote something additional to moebiusband, but i can't read it i guess he wrote moebiusband\ inner circle ? it doesnt matter, cylinder is ok.

Comment: Your map $S^1\times [-\frac{\pi}{2}, \frac{\pi}{2}] \to S^2$ doesn't make sense. Also, what do you mean by $U_2 = p(S^1\times(-\frac{\pi}{4}, \frac{\pi}{4})$? You said $p$ is the projection $S^2 \to \mathbb{R}P^2$, but $S^1\times(-\frac{\pi}{4}, \frac{\pi}{4})$ is not a subset of $S^2$. Do you mean the image of $S^1\times(-\frac{\pi}{4}, \frac{\pi}{4})$ in $S^2$ under the map $S^1\times[-\frac{\pi}{2}, \frac{\pi}{2}] \to S^2$?

Comment: @Michael Albanese, Yes i think otherwise it doesn't make sense.

Comment: In order to understand what $U_2$ is, you need to know what the map $S^1\times[-\frac{\pi}{2}, \frac{\pi}{2}] \to S^2$ is. As written, it doesn't make any sense. Do you know what that map should be?

Comment: No the map is OK, did you notice that x is an element of $S^1$, and $(x,t)\mapsto cos(t)(x,0,0)+sin(t)(0,0,1)$ is just a parametrization of $S^2$

Comment: First of all, that is not what you wrote. In addition, $\cos t(x, 0, 0) +\sin t(0, 0, 1)$ is an element of $S^2$ only when $x^2 = 1$, which is not true for all $x \in S^1$ (it is only true for $x = \pm 1$).

Answer (score 3):

Issues with the proof aside, here is the answer to your question. Let $A = 1$, $B = \langle b \rangle \cong \Bbb Z$, $A \cap B = \langle c \rangle \cong \Bbb Z$.

Let $\psi_1$, $\psi_2$ be the inclusion maps from $A \cap B$ to $A$, $B$ respectively. Since $A$ is trivial, $\psi_1$ is trivial too. As loops, the generator of $A \cap B$ goes twice around the generator of $B$. Hence $\psi_2(c) = b^2$.

We have
$$
A * B = \langle b \rangle,
$$
and
$$
N = \langle b^2 \rangle.
$$

Thus
$$
(A * B) / N = \langle b \mid b^2 \rangle \cong \Bbb Z / 2 \Bbb Z
$$

Comment: YES, i asked exactly this. what do you mean mean ''as loops the generator of $A\cap B$ goes twice around the generator of $B$''

Comment: @derivative Think of $\Bbb R \textrm P^2$ as a circle with a disk attached such that the boundary of the disk goes twice around the circle. Let $A$ be the interior of the disk, $B$ a small neighborhood around the circle. A loop in $A \cap B$ goes twice around the circle, just like the boundary of the Möbius band.

Answer (score 1):

In general $A *_C B$ means: you are given homomorphisms $\alpha: C \to A$
and $\beta:C \to B$ (these are not typically included in the notation, but are a crucial part of the data!).  You then take a the free product of $A$ and $B$,
and finally, take the maximal quotient in which $\alpha(c)$ and $\beta(c)$ are identified, for all $c \in C$.

Now if $A = 1$, the trivial group, then this is just the same as taking the maximal quotient of $B$ in which $\beta(C)$ is identified to $1$; equivalently,
the quotient of $B$ by the normal subgroup generated by $\beta(C)$.

Now if $B$ and $C$ are $\mathbb Z$ (which is in particular abelian, so that any subgroup is normal), and you *are told* that $1 *_C B = \mathbb Z/2 \mathbb Z$, then the image of $\beta$ must be $2\mathbb Z$.  This pretty much pins down $\beta$ (it fixes it up to a sign).

This should let you reverse engineer the problem/proof you are trying to understand.